# Long response times for my Firebase Firestore simple query (10 - 30 seconds each)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore query that to me seems like it should be operating rather quickly, but instead it is taking 10 - 30 seconds per round trip. I'm using the Firebase ios sdk version 4.5.0 for Swift 4, Xcode version: 9.1. My Firestore pod is also 4.5.0.

I have a Firestore collection called locations with 3,500 location documents in it. My query gets all location documents from the locations collection where the field, "geohash_6," is equal to "9q8yyq." To me that seems like it should be a rather simple query to execute, but it's taking a really long time each time I call it.

The problem is, I need to call this query for 5 different geohash each update. I'm hoping to have a quicker load time to the UI than 10 seconds per query and definitely quicker than 30. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? It seems even if I were to use elasticsearch or similar search/indexing service, serving up the full firestore results identified by the search service would still take 10 - 30 seconds.

Thanks!

---

Here is my actual query: Firestore.firestore().collection("locations").whereField("geohash_6", isEqualTo: "9q8yyq")

Here is a debug log I had it output so I can see the times of a few consecutive requests:

31 seconds:
load: running updateLocationStore()
load: going out for locations in 9q8yyq at 2017-11-28T14:20:35
load: back with locations in 9q8yyq at 2017-11-28T14:21:06

13 seconds: 
load: running updateLocationStore()
load: going out for locations in 9q8yyw at 2017-11-28T14:21:06
load: back with locations in 9q8yyw at 2017-11-28T14:21:19

14 seconds:
load: running updateLocationStore()
load: going out for locations in 9q8yyr at 2017-11-28T14:21:19
load: back with locations in 9q8yyr at 2017-11-28T14:21:33

12 seconds:
load: running updateLocationStore()
load: going out for locations in 9q8yyx at 2017-11-28T14:21:33
load: back with locations in 9q8yyx at 2017-11-28T14:21:45

Comment: It looks like the first one is always 30 seconds or so, which I understand is the initial connection and will take longer than the rest. Each one after is right about 13 seconds pretty reliably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore document get() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675765/firestore-document-get-performance)

Comment: Having same problem, following for an answer.  Seems to be problem whether or not I use the "limit" option.

Comment: Can you post your code or some other details about your Firestore configuration?